Problem selecting rows meeting specific conditions in Goolge-Sheets and NodeJS
My webapp backend is in Node.js, used for reading/writing to/from a Google Sheets spreadsheet.
I want to use a query that will retrieve only rows which meet specific conditions, but haven't been able to do this.
[Note: I'd like to save on traffic, and fetch only the filtered data rather than fetch everything and filter them locally]
The following method receives a single (string) parameter, customerID.
Ultimately I want retrieve the single row where the cutomerID column matches the supplied parameter, and the status column equals New
(column2==customerID) && (column4=='New')
Here's what I have so far:
async function getDraftOrderByID(customerID) {
        try {
            const auth = new GoogleAuth({ scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/ auth/spreadsheets.readonly'});
            const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth });
            const spreadsheetId = 'MY-SPREADSHEET-ID';
            const range = 'Orders!A3:D9';
            const filter = 'column2 = "cid444"';

            const myRetrievedData = await sheets.spreadsheets.values. get({
                spreadsheetId,
                range,
            });

            console.log('Retrieved from ORDERS tab: ', myRetrievedData.data.values);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error retrieving draft Order ID :((( ', error);
            throw error;
        }

Sample contents of the sheet:



OrderID
CustomerID
OrderDate
Status




X8G3F7
cid222
23FEB2024
Complete


V3B4R3
cid444
18MAR2024
New


E5T2A2
cid9999
18APR2023
Complete


Y5H5J6
cid444
27DEC2023
progress



if method is run for cid444, it should retrieve the contents of row 2, but currently running this method results in returning all rows in range which are 3,4,5:
[
[ 'V3B4R3' , 'cid444' , '18MAR2024' , 'New' ]
[ 'E5T2A2' , 'cid9999' , '18APR2023' , 'Complete' ]
[ 'Y5H5J6' , 'cid444' , '27DEC2023' , 'progress' ]
]
in an attempt to evaluate proposed solutions, I added the "filter" variable as a third parameter to values.get,
also tried using "values.batchGetByDataFilter" and defining a filter criteria JSON. None worked so far.
Mostly, errors would look like:
GaxiosError: Invalid JSON payload received.
Unknown name "filter": Cannot bind query parameter.
Field 'filter' could not be found in request message.

Suggestion:
Since myRetrievedData.data.values already returns a 2D array, you can instead use filter to only return rows with a matching CustomerId and a status of New
I was able to get your desired result by replacing:
console.log('Retrieved from ORDERS tab: ', myRetrievedData.data.values);

with:
console.log('Retrieved from ORDERS tab: ',
  myRetrievedData.data.values.filter(
    row => row[1] == customerID && row[3] == 'New'
  ));

Edit:
Filtering results based on values is currently not possible via Sheets API. As a workaround, You can query using Google Visualization API instead.
Do try this modified version of your script:
function getDraftOrderByID(customerID) {
  const auth = new GoogleAuth({
    scopes: "https://www.googleapis.com/ auth/spreadsheets.readonly",
  });

  auth.getRequestHeaders().then((authorization) => {
    const spreadsheetId = "spreadsheet-id"; //Replace this with the spreadsheet ID .
    const sheetId = 0; // Please set the sheet ID.
    //The Sheet ID is the number that appears after the "gid=" in the spreadsheet URL

    let qs = {
      gid: sheetId,
      tqx: "out:csv",
      tq: `Select A,B,C,D Where B = '${customerID}' and D = 'New' Label A '', B '', C '', D ''`,
    };


    let options = {
      url: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${spreadsheetId}/gviz/tq`,
      qs: qs,
      method: "get",
      headers: authorization,
    };

    request(options, (err, res, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error retrieving draft Order ID :((( ", err);
        return;
      }
      let data = result.replaceAll('"', '').split(",");
      console.log("Retrieved from ORDERS tab:", data);
    });
  });
}

Reference:

filter()


I'd like to save on traffic, and fetch only the filtered data rather than fetch everything and filter them locally

Unfortunately, it's currently not possible to filter rows based on column values during a Sheets API call. The existing API method batchGetByDataFilter only filters by developer metadata and by ranges but not by values. I've updated my answer to query using Google Visualization API instead.
